# Can't update p:tab content

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to update the content of a selected tab, but no methods seem to work.

This sort of what I have:

```
<h:form id="tabsForm">

    <p:tabView id="tabs"
               dynamic="true"
               cache="false"
               value="#{mainPage.versions}"
               var="version"
               scrollable="true">

        <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{mainPage.onTabChange}" />
        <p:ajax event="tabClose" listener="#{mainPage.onTabClose}" />

        <p:tab id="version" title="#{version.value}" closable="true">

          <p:poll interval="5" update=":tabsForm:tabs" oncomplete="doSomething()"/>

          CONTENT GOES HERE (ALSO NEEDS TO BE UPDATED)

        </p:tab>

    </p:tabView>

</h:form>
```

The Line:

`<p:poll interval="60" update=":tabsForm:tabs" oncomplete="doSomething()"/>`

Supposed to update the content inside each tab every 60 seconds, The problem is, it will always select the first tab after the `update`.

I tried to update a tab separately, this way:

`<p:poll interval="60" update=":tabsForm:tabs:version" oncomplete="doSomething()"/>`

But I get an exception:

> Can not update component "org.primefaces.component.tabview.Tab" with id "tabsForm:tabs:0:version" without a attached renderer. Expression ":tabsForm:tabs:version" referenced from "tabsForm:tabs:0:j_idt14"

I also tried a lot of other methods from questions I found here on SO, but nothing is working.
It either updates and selects the first tab for me or doesn't update at all.

Comment: Did you try wrapping the content to be updated in an `ui:fragment`, give that an id and update that? If not, why not? If you did what was the problem?

Comment: And if you need to keep the selected tab open after an update of all the tabs, there are at least 2 similar questions about that in Stackoverflow: https://www.google.com/search?q=primefaces+keep+selected+tab+open+stackoverflow

Comment: Does `update="version"` not solve your problem?

Comment: @TheBitman: that won't work either... `p:tab` does not have a renderer so it cannot be updated. You'll most likely get the same error then that is in the question already.

Comment: as @kukeltje said : the tab component has not renderer, so you should bind the activeIndex to a bean property to show the right tab on tabview update

Comment: But just updating the content of one tab would be better performance wise

Comment: you said : we must update the tabview (it has a renderer) and process the tab. the tabchange should be handled by ajax

Comment: The p:poll is to make ajax calls and execute listener on the jsf backing bean but you do not seem to be having a listener. Then what is the purpose of it and what are you trying to update on the tab without any new values to update ?

Comment: @Kukeltje I tried to wrapping it like you suggested, But I get the error: `Can not update component "com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.ComponentRef" with id "tabsForm:tabs:0:versionContent" without a attached renderer. Expression "versionContent" referenced from "tabsForm:tabs:0:j_idt25"`

Comment: @OTM I have another process running and updating the DB, the content needs to be constantly refreshed because to show the user the latest results. Refreshing the whole page would just throw the user back to the first tab.

Comment: @Kukeltje instead of wrapping with ui:fragment, I wrapped it with h:panelGroup and suddenly it works. Same idea but with a different component. I would like to give you credit, so please post the answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Kukeltje It didn't quite work as expected, in the second rendering, it was loading the content of the first tab instead of the one I selected.
To fix this I added `activeIndex` to the `tabview` and `update="versionContent#{mainpage.versionActiveIndex}"`. Now it works.

Comment: These were two totally unrelated problems. Then you still updated a larger component. The last one has multiple q/a in stackoverflow. And if updating a `:ui:fragment` did not work I wonder what JSF version and implementation you are using

Comment: @Kukeltje I don't see any mention of my JSF version in the project, but the primefaces version is 6.1.RC3

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to put the  tag inside the dynamic tabView. That will create a poll for each individual tab. Instead you want to use one poll tag to update the tab. If you are OK with updating all tabs and keeping focus on the current tab then just..

```
<h:form id="tabsForm">

    <p:tabView id="tabs"
           cache="false"
           value="#{mainPage.versions}"
           var="version"
           scrollable="true">

      <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{mainPage.onTabChange}" />
      <p:ajax event="tabClose" listener="#{mainPage.onTabClose}" />

      <p:tab id="version" title="#{version.value}" closable="true">

        CONTENT GOES HERE (ALSO NEEDS TO BE UPDATED)

      </p:tab>

    </p:tabView>
    <p:poll interval="60" listener="#{mainPage.updateComponent('tabsForm:tabs:version')}" oncomplete="doSomething();"/>

</h:form>
```

in javascript

```
//if this is needed ***
function doSomething() { 
    $("#tabsForm\\:tabs ul li.ui-tabs-selected).click();
}
```

and in mainPage:

```
public void updateComponent(String compId){
     RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(compId);
}
```

I removed the "dynamic=true" (seems to cause more problems). Get rid of the error message by updating the component from the backing bean through a listener.

Updating individual tabs is more difficult and prone to strange behavior. You can try, but it seems to only work if the tabIndex is not 0. You would capture the tabIndex onTabChange event with

```
public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event) {
    tabIndex = ((TabView) event.getSource()).getIndex();
}
//getter setter tabIndex
```

Your poll tag would be something like

```
<p:poll interval="60" listener="#{mainPage.updateComponent('tabsForm:tabs:' += mainPage.tabIndex += ':version')}" oncomplete="doSomething();"/>
```

apparently += is only for EL 3.0, you could use .concat instead. My PF version is 6.0

Comment: Did you have a similar or **identical** issue? Since you cannot update a single tab... You update all tabs in your code. That works. But that that is not what the OP requested.

Comment: Are you **sure** the content of the just this tab is updated? And what PF version do you use? Isn't the some 'auto update' component inside it that by 'accident' is also updated?